# Tag rename request

Tags: feature-request, tags

Can we rename [pharmacokinetic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmacokinetic) and [pharmacodynamic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmacodynamic) to [pharmacokinetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmacokinetics) and [pharmacodynamics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmacodynamics), respectively?

The current tag names are used as adjectives and are not the names of the fields of study.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done, I renamed the tags. The tag wikis need to be redone as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes. We should start working on tag-wikis for other tags too.

Comment: What needs to be done there? Working on the tags and the wiki is still a bit mysterious.

Comment: @Chris I think with the rename the wiki info is lost. We have to redo it. In general we should improve our tag-wikis.